# Delphi RadStudio 10.2 running on VMWare Fusion : Keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-shortcuts, vmware-fusion

I'm trying to work on a personal project at home using the free Delphi RADstudio 10.2 on my Mac thru VMware Fusion running Windows 8

I can't access any of the most used keyboard shortcuts :

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>*mouseClick*</kbd> :  to go to the signature of the method
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> : to create/insert the implementation part of a method's signature
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> : to search within my project | a directory

I've tried Malcom Groves' advice: disabling keyboard shortcuts from mac OS host ('RAD Studio/AppMethod keystrokes vs VMWare Fusion Unity View', http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1716) to no avail ...

thanks for your inputs : solving this minor annoyance will speed up the project

Comment: I don't use VMWare Fusion, I use Parallels instead, but just FWIW, sometimes I must restart the VM to make these changes work.

Comment: Have you tried this? From the VMWare menu, 'Virtual Machine', 'Settings', 'Keyboard & Mouse'. From here you should see profiles for keyboard mappings.  I think the default is 'Mac Profile', There should be a default for PC, but if not, you may need to create one or edit an existing one.  You didn't specify which version of VMWare you have, but here's an article for 6. https://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.fusion.help.doc%2FGUID-003F98BE-B8DE-48CC-937A-4A6E2D06439F.html